# <head/> tag is generating automatically in ajax file when enabled pagespeed

Tags: pagespeed

I had enabled pagespeed in apache server. In that `<head/>` is automatically creating in all ajax file.

For example when I see the response tag using Firebug, I am getting the below output:

```
<head/><p>
Images below the fold (the ones lower than window bottom) are not loaded. When scrolling down
they are loaded when needed. Empty cache and shift-reload to test again. Compare this to page
where plugin is <a href="disabled.html">disabled</a>, same page with
<a href="enabled_fadein.html">fadein effect</a>, page with <a href="enabled_wide.html">wide
layout</a> or wide content <a href="enabled_wide_container.html">inside container</a>.
</p>
```

instead of:

```
<p>
Images below the fold (the ones lower than window bottom) are not loaded. When scrolling down
they are loaded when needed. Empty cache and shift-reload to test again. Compare this to page
where plugin is <a href="disabled.html">disabled</a>, same page with
<a href="enabled_fadein.html">fadein effect</a>, page with <a href="enabled_wide.html">wide
layout</a> or wide content <a href="enabled_wide_container.html">inside container</a>.
</p>
```

How I can remove the `<head/>` tag?

Comment: Please preview your post before submitting it to ensure that it displays correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is added by the default mod_pagespeed [`add_head`](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-head-add) filter. You can disable it with:

```
ModPagespeedDisableFilters add_head
```

However, note that this filter is needed for many other filters which will only write contents in the  element.

Comment: I had tried by adding ModPagespeedDisableFilters add_head in the pagespeed.conf, but no change. getting same <head/> tag in the page.

Comment: It looks like this filter is automatically enabled by many others: https://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/source/browse/trunk/src/net/instaweb/rewriter/rewrite_driver.cc#987 so you would have to disable kAddBaseTag, kAddHead, kAddInstrumentation, kCombineHeads, kDeterministicJs, kHandleNoscriptRedirect, kMakeGoogleAnalyticsAsync, kMoveCssAboveScripts and kMoveCssToHead. But that's a lot of work just to save 7 bytes. Any particular reason you want to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe easier than both of the other options. Set your header in php to something other html/txt:

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
```

seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way to overcome this is to activate the "**[OptimizeForBandwidth](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/optimize-for-bandwidth)**" rewrite level instead of the CoreFilters

```
ModPagespeedRewriteLevel OptimizeForBandwidth
```